# SQLalchemy: discrepancy between iteration + count and func.count() results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a series of classes defined like this (**note**: they extend an already-existing database through `automap`, so references to the columns below may not reflect the classes here):

```
class VariantAssociation(Base):

    __tablename__ = "sample_variant_association"

    vid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("variants.variant_id"),
                primary_key=True, index=True)
    sid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("samples.sample_id"),
                primary_key=True, index=True)

    vdepth = Column(Integer, index=True)
    valt_depth = Column(Integer, index=True)
    gt = Column(Text)
    gt_type = Column(Integer)
    fraction = Column(Float, index=True)

    variant = relationship("Variant", back_populates="samples")
    sample = relationship("Samples", back_populates="variants")


class Variant(Base):

    __tablename__ = "variants"

    variant_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    info = deferred(Column(LargeBinary))

    samples = relationship("VariantAssociation",
                        back_populates="variant")

    def __repr__(self):

        data = "<Variant {chrom}:{start}-{end} {gene} {ref}/{alt} {type}>"

        return data.format(chrom=self.chrom,
                        start=self.start,
                        end=self.end,
                        gene=self.gene,
                        ref=self.ref,
                        alt=self.alt,
                        type=self.type)


class Samples(Base):

    __tablename__ = "samples"

    sample_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(Text, index=True)
    variants = relationship("VariantAssociation",
                            back_populates="sample")
```

They are assembled in a rather complex query, but slimmed down here:

```
query = session.query(Variant).join(VariantAssociation.variant_id).join(Samples)
query = query.filter(VariantAssociation.vdepth >= 60)
```

Now, I want to count the combinations of two columns: `ref` and `alt`.

I thought it would be simple as:

```
query = query.with_entities(Variant.ref, Variant.alt, 
    func.count()).distinct().group_by(gemini.Variant.ref, gemini.Variant.alt)
```

Which yields (one row example):

```
('A', 'C', 308)
```

However, if I just iterate on the query and count:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
counts  = defaultdict(Counter)
for row in query.with_entities(Variant.ref, Variant.alt):
    counts[f"{row.ref}>{row.alt}"].update(["present"])
```

gives me

```
'A>C': Counter({'present': 155})
```

Nearly the *half* of what I found through `count`. I know the latter is correct, and not the former. But I would like to use the former as the latter can be extremely slow (large SQLite database).

Did I set up counting incorrectly?

EDIT: As requested, the full query for `count` (includes a couple more filters from the DB itself)

```
SELECT DISTINCT variants.ref AS variants_ref, variants.alt AS variants_alt, count(*) AS count_1 
FROM variants JOIN sample_variant_association ON variants.variant_id = sample_variant_association.vid JOIN
samples ON samples.sample_id = sample_variant_association.sid 
WHERE sample_variant_association.gt_type != ? AND variants.impact NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?) AND
sample_variant_association.vdepth >= ? AND sample_variant_association.fraction >= ? AND variants.chrom NOT IN (?,
?) AND variants.aaf_1kg_eur < ? AND variants.type = ? AND sample_variant_association.fraction >= ? AND
sample_variant_association.vdepth >= ? GROUP BY variants.ref, variants.alt
```

And the one used to iterate:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT variants.ref AS variants_ref, variants.alt AS variants_alt 
FROM variants JOIN sample_variant_association ON variants.variant_id = sample_variant_association.vid JOIN
samples ON samples.sample_id = sample_variant_association.sid 
WHERE sample_variant_association.gt_type != ? AND variants.impact NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?) AND
sample_variant_association.vdepth >= ? AND sample_variant_association.fraction >= ? AND variants.chrom NOT IN (?,
?) AND variants.aaf_1kg_eur < ? AND variants.type = ? AND sample_variant_association.fraction >= ? AND
sample_variant_association.vdepth >= ?
```

EDIT 2: I traced this to the presence of duplicated variant_ids in the base query:

```
query.with_entities(gemini.Variant.variant_id).count()
18288
query.with_entities(gemini.Variant.variant_id).distinct().count()
14437
```

So the issue is different than what I had originally thought. Somehow the duplicate records are accounted for in the loop, but not with `func.count()`.

Comment: can you share the query generated `str(query)`

Comment: To add to what @shanmuga said, please share the queries used in both cases.

Comment: Added both queries, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subqueries worked, by removing first the duplicates:

```
id_subquery = query.with_entities(Variant.variant_id).distinct().subquery()
```

then getting the actual data:

```
c_query = session.query(Variant.ref, Variant.alt, func.count(1))
c_query = c_query.filter(Variant.variant_id.in_(id_subquery))
c_query = c_query.group_by(Variant.ref, Variant.alt)

c_query.first()
('A', 'C', 155)
```